# Differing python codes for same desired result produce differing results...trying to understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have posted this on a different site, but haven't received an answer there...so posting here to get an answer that will help me understand what is going on. My original post is below:

So, I did my own code for this before going back and viewing the video of the instructor walking through this exercise.

My code:

```
(01)    hours = input('How many hours did you work?')
(02)    rate = input('How much do you make per hour?')
(03)    if float(hours) <= 40:
(04)        strhrs = hours # strhrs = straight-time hours
(05)    else:
(06)        reghrs = 40
(07)        othrs = float(hours)-40 # othrs = over-time hours
(08)        strhrs = 0
(09)    if strhrs != 0:
(10)        pay = float(strhrs)*float(rate)
(11)    else:
(12)        regpay = float(reghrs)*float(rate)
(13)        otpay = (float(rate)*1.5)*float(othrs)
(14)        pay = regpay+otpay
(15)    print(pay)
```

Then, I went back and watch the video covering this exercise. Obviously our codes are going to be a little different. Here is what the instructor coded:

Instructor's code:

```
(01)    sh = input("Enter Hours: ")
(02)    sr = input("Enter Rate: ")
(03)    fh = float(sh)
(04)    fr = float(sr)

(05)

(06)    if fh > 40 :
(07)        reg = fr * fh
(08)        otp = (fh-40.0)*(fr*0.5)
(09)        xp = reg + otp
(10)    else:
(11)        xp = hours * rate

(12)

(13)    print("Pay:",xp)
```

My question is, with the "otpay" (line 13 of my code) calculating the rate*1.5, I'm getting the same result as "otp" (line 8 in the instructor's code) that calculates fr*0.5.

What is the difference in how Python is handling the two pieces of code (rate * 1.5 VS float rate * 0.5)?

If I put in "1.5" in the instructor's code, the result is complete different (it calculates to 2.5 times the normal rate of pay instead of 1.5 times the normal rate of pay). I'm not seeing what the difference in syntax is that would cause this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a comment on your code: What's the difference between straight-time hours and regular hours? There is none. You could simplify your code by not making that distinction. Also, all those float casts are unnecessary AFAICT.

Like this (untested)

```py
hours = input('How many hours did you work?')
rate = input('How much do you make per hour?')
if hours <= 40:
    reghrs = hours  # reghrs = regular hours
    othrs = 0  # othrs = over-time hours
else:
    reghrs = 40
    othrs = hours-40
regpay = reghrs*rate
otpay = (rate*1.5)*othrs
pay = regpay+otpay
print(pay)
```

To answer your question: You're just using a different way to come to the same result. You're computing `payment for the first 40 hours (regpay)` + `payment for the overtime time (otpay)`. Your instructor is computing `regular payment for the time worked (reg)` + `additional payment for overtime (otp)`.

Btw: Please tell your instructor to use better variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...that does seem like a cleaner, more simple way to do it.

So, I'm still wondering if there is something that I'm not seeing that I need to be careful with in order to get the result I want.

The instructor's code that I'm not understanding is:
`otp = (fh-40.0)*(fr*0.5)`.
Why does putting using **fr*1.5** result in calculating the **rate x 2.5** instead of the normal **rate x 1.5**?

Comment: Ok, let's look at your instructor's code. `reg = fr * fh` Notice how this line already includes the base payment for ALL hours worked. Not just the first 40, but the overtime hours also! That's why you only need to add 0.5 times the hourly rate for the overtime hours.

Comment: Draw yourself a diagram of payment over time. It should be shaped like a rotated L. There are 2 obvious ways to split the L into rectangles. You chose one of them, your instructor the other.